# NestJs microservices architecture common code with separated docker and env files: Monorepo or TS config + Nest cli config?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nestjs-config

What is the best solution for common code in the NestJS microservices project?

Is: microservices (communication via REST API) with self-sufficient packages, docker and env files, utils + interfaces + DTOs + etc

Need: to have utils + interfaces + DTOs + etc as common in one place, and good to have shared package dependencies to have consistent in dependence-modules versions

Problem:
a) via TS config - Nest cli problems with entry points and lost other cli feature as in monorepo
b) via monorepo - it's run via 1 entry point and problems with docker files and separated environments (sometimes in dev process 1 server could be looks at other one locally, sometimes to dev or prod and it's configured by separated for each server .env[prod/dev/dev.local] files)